# jupyterhub new users with too many default example file and folder

Tags: azure, jupyterhub

i have an istance of Linux Data Science Virtual Machine on Azure and jupyterhub. It works very well, but when i create new users, jupyterhub create a lot of example file in his enviroment. I need to remove them/ substitute with own example... there is a file option where i can setup it?

[image: jupyterhub]

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files in /etc/skel are copied to a new user's home directory when her account is created. You will find the default notebooks there, under /etc/skel/notebooks. This will not update accounts you've already created but will apply to all new accounts.